# iOS dispatch_async, crash on iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm making server requests to a server on different threads. When they are done loading, I get a delegate callback which updates a tableView. At first, I noticed some strange behavior, and figured it might be because some UI elements weren't performed on the main thread.

I added the code below, which solved the problem, but the code crashed on iOS 4 devices (Turns out DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND isn't compatible with iOS 4)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^(void) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    //Update view code etc...
  });
});
```

If I remove the first `dispatch_async`, and only call `dispatch_get_main_queue`, the code runs fine:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
  //Update view code etc...
});
```

Before sending in my update to Apple, I wanted to ask if this is okay to do? Will the code run correctly on iOS 4 devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` on devices lower than iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is only available in iOS 5 and upper

From apple docs

> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND Items dispatched to the queue run
>   at background priority; the queue is scheduled for execution after all
>   high priority queues have been scheduled and the system runs items on
>   a thread whose priority is set for background status. Such a thread
>   has the lowest priority and any disk I/O is throttled to minimize the
>   impact on the system. Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

So if you are thinking of distributing your app for iOS 4 too, then you cant use it

Source [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/dispatch_queue_priority_t)

However if you remove the `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`, your current code will only run in the main ui thread, wich may lead to slow downs when you are doing your remote requests

Comment: Thanks for reply. You said it will only run in the main thread, but only for the portion of the code inside the brackets right? I only put the dispatch_async in the callback after all the background stuff have completed.